# Notation in fundamental theorem of homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ and $G^\prime$ be two groups and $\phi : G\rightarrow G^\prime $be an onto-homomorphism. Let $H= \ker\phi$ Then the quotient group $G/H \simeq G^\prime$.

What does this '$\simeq$' symbol denote?

Comment: This symbol means that the groups are isomorphic. Often they also use the symbol $\cong$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This symbol means "isomorphism". In general two mathematical structures are isomorphic, if there is a bijective function that maps elements from one structure to the other which contains the structural properties.

Specifically groups $(G,\circ),(H,*)$ are isomorphic $G\simeq H$ as groups if there exists a bijective $f:G \to H$ with
$$
f(g\circ h) = f(g) * f(h)
$$
for all $g,h\in G$

More details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism

However, if you don't know what $\simeq$ means, maybe you should read something about that first before going to more complex theorems as the homomorphism theorem.